# Which control to use for needed view?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to populate a control like a ListView or TableView etc. with data for a meeting agenda.  But, I want the functionality you see below.

As the user scrolls down the items, the latest meeting slot time "sticks" at the top until all its meetings have scrolled off.  Then the next one pushes it up and takes its place.

Is this possible in Xamarin Forms?  I'm building in VS 2022 (newbie).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in Xamarin Forms. And this is related to a feature request on Github:[Able to toggle sticky group headers in CollectionView #8656](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8656).

You can use a grouped [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) and use custom renderer to dynamically stick the header at the top of the `CollectionView` when scrolling it. Here's a demo [FormsStickyHeaders](https://github.com/xamcat/Scratch/tree/master/FormsStickyHeaders) provided by Dean for your reference.